# Error - The import com.google can not be resolved

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I got an error when I wrote the code

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

in eclipse. The error is `The import com.google can not be resolved.`

Please anybody give suggestion to fix this problem.

Answer (score 33):

Bring up your project properties, and go to Android. Do you have an Android target selected that includes the Google APIs? Perhaps you just have a generic Android target.

Answer (score 5):

As Jim said, you have to select "Google APIs" (which is Android x.x + Google APIs) instead of something like "Android 2.2" in your project's properties.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure you have installed Google API

Then set your project's properties in Eclipse to check off the Google APIs version of the SDK.

and Make sure you have include this library in AndroidManifest FIle

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```