# How to Import Google APIs for Android Development

Tags: android, google-places-api

As a followup to this question: [Error - The import com.google can not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535953/error-the-import-com-google-can-not-be-resolved), I was wondering how one can import the necessary Google APIs.

Specifically, I need to:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
```

I have downloaded Google Play via the Android SDK Manager as suggested by ([The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved))

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find detailed instructions for this on the developer site here:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to do following steps

1.go to your android extra folder inside your android sdk.

2.then go to google folder and then you will find google play services folder.

3.Inside google play services, you will find libproject folder.You have to import this as     your library project in your workspace.

4.Add this library project in your application as library.

Note - If you wont find libproject folder in your google play services folder then update your google play service in your sdk.