# How to use com.google.android.collect.list in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I want to use `com.google.android.collect.List` in my `apk`. But I don't understand which library I should include in the project.

I see that this class must be in `frameworks/base/core`. And I think that  `frameworks/base/core` is included in `framework.jar` or `framework2.jar`.

But, `framework.jar` and `framework2.jar` from my phone contains `odex` files, and Android Studio can't use it.

Can anyone explain to me how to use classes from frameworks/base/core in `apk`?

In addition, how I understand android sdk don't include frameworks/base/core.

Comment: First, it's `com.google.android.collect.Lists` with a `s`, then you should really read a starter tutorial, maybe http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I just made ​​a mistake in the text

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535953/error-the-import-com-google-can-not-be-resolved

Comment: I think my question not related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535953/error-the-import-com-google-can-not-be-resolved. Because to use google maps api i can install  Google Play services with sdk manager and enable it in  project. But framework/base can't installed with sdk manager

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526133/build-android-branch-missing-imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. It's not easy way. I've download android source codes and compile it. Then i get jar file with compiled classes and set as library for my project. I know that it's crazy solution :) but i don't found another way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to download the android source code. If you are looking for Lists, Maps then use Guava library.